# Подскажите модем для arduino/stm8/android/Linux c++

Tags: c++, arduino, модемы

Доброго времени суток.
Есть несколько идей для экспериментов с ардуино, в рамках которых надо передавать данные с собственно ардуины/stm8 на телефон под андроидом, или на удалённый компьютер. Логичнее было бы использовать SIM900 и bluetooth модуль, но появилась идея использовать аудиоканал.
В первом случае, ардуина подключается в гнездо наушников (даже где-то готовый шилд видал), а во втором к старому мобильнику, в который вставлена симка некоего оператора с бесплатными звонками внутри сети.
Вообщем, может кто подсказать реализацию софтмодема на c/c++, которая позволить:

1. Воспроизводить / записывать аудио через ШИМ на ардуино / stm8
2. Генерировать / понимать RAW/WAV-поток 8000 бит моно для подачи в USB-модем

Нужна либо библиотека с примерами под 1 и 2 пункты, либо сам принцип, как это реализовать "для чайника".
Впринципе, я понял, что для генерации сигнала можно ШИМом генерировать импульсы разной длины/частоты для нулей и единиц, но вот как распознать их - не до конца ясно.

Comment: Да, принимать сигнал на ПК планируется в программе на c/c++ под линуксом. Могу использовать QT.

Comment: Научитесь сначала синтезировать сам модемный сигнал - для этого особое железо не нужно, достаточно изучить протокол, например, V.21.

Вывод звука - дело чисто техническое.

Answer (score 1):

При помощи ШИМ-а невозможно промодулировать сигнал для описанных выше задач. ШИМ-это всего лишь перепады уровней между 0 и +5 в со скважностью от 1/255 до 255/255 на частоте около 500 Гц(если использовать стоковую библиотеку Ардуино).Есть куча других решений.

Comment: >Есть куча других решений. Каких?

Comment: Использовать bluetooth модуль, или ethernet-шилд,и на худой конец на любой ардуйне есть хотя бы один UART.

Comment: Да, но использовать планируется на даче с уже имеющимся телефоном, который не умеет GPRS.

Comment: Не совсем понятно,причем тут gprs)))если надо передавать/получать данные Ардуинке,есть очень классная прога под Android ,лежит тут --http://dkgadget.net/ru , поскольку синий зуб есть почти в каждом смартфоне,то в чем же дело?)))